# Wordpress custom fields displaying image name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom field where the user can select the background of a div. However in the top right hand corner or the screen it displays this:

**35, , 4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693, , , image/jpeg, http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693.jpg, 1200, 1200, Array');**

The code I am using to let the user select the background (as well as its content) is:

```
<?php $image = get_field( 'slide_bg1' );
if ( !empty( $image ) ) { ?>
    <div class="slide1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>');">
<?php the_field('slide_bg1'); ?>');<div class="slide1-cont"><p class="slide-text"><h1><?php the_field('slide_title1'); ?></h1><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/line.png" /></p>
<p><?php the_field('slide_content1'); ?></p></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

var_dump of $image:

array(10) { ["id"]=> int(35) ["alt"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(28) "4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["url"]=> string(86) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693.jpg" ["width"]=> int(1200) ["height"]=> int(1200) ["sizes"]=> array(9) { ["thumbnail"]=> string(94) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693-150x150.jpg" ["thumbnail-width"]=> int(150) ["thumbnail-height"]=> int(150) ["medium"]=> string(94) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693-300x300.jpg" ["medium-width"]=> int(300) ["medium-height"]=> int(300) ["large"]=> string(96) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693-1024x1024.jpg" ["large-width"]=> int(900) ["large-height"]=> int(900) } }

*Screenshot of top left corner*

[image: screen shot of top left corner]

Screenshot of custom field
[image]

How do I get rid of this text? Is it an error?

Comment: is your site live? I am guessing your code is displaying the details of the image file. Try to narrow down by commenting out the echos one at a time

Comment: no it's locally at the moment. So it must be this line?

<div class="slide1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>');">

I need this as this is what lets the user set the div background as an image

Comment: do the var_dump of $image and post it here

Comment: array(10) { ["id"]=> int(35) ["alt"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(28) "4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["url"]=> string(86) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693.jpg" ["width"]=> int(1200) ["height"]=> int(1200) ["sizes"]=> array(9) { ["thumbnail"]=> string(94) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693-150x150.jpg" ["thumbnail-width"]=>

Comment: int(150) ["thumbnail-height"]=> int(150) ["medium"]=> string(94) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693-300x300.jpg" ["medium-width"]=> int(300) ["medium-height"]=> int(300) ["large"]=> string(96) "http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4c5a6729201043.55e72a8144693-1024x1024.jpg" ["large-width"]=> int(900) ["large-height"]=> int(900) } }

Comment: Had to post it over 2 comments as it was too long...is this what you meant?

Comment: you could have just edited your question :)

Comment: edited into question now, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96267/discussion-between-lucky-chingi-and-5kud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is added here

```
<?php $image = get_field( 'slide_bg1' ); 
if ( !empty( $image ) ) { ?> 
<div class="slide1" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);"> 
<div class="slide1-cont"><p class="slide-text"><h1><?php the_field('slide_title1'); ?></h1><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/line.png" /></p> 
<p><?php the_field('slide_content1'); ?></p></div> 
</div> 
<?php } ;?>
```